# useEffect has a missing dependency that's a const function

Tags: reactjs

```
useEffect(() => {
    let interval = null;
    if (isOn) {
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        counting();
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [isOn, currentTimeMs]);


const counting = () => {
    setCurrentTimeMs(currentTimeMs + 1);
};
```

I thought the dependency of useEffect only accepted variables, but it also asks me to put a function that's a const? Why is that? Is that an error with webpack or something?

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'counting'. Either include
>   it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

I also am getting another warning:

> The 'counting' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line
>   39) change on every render. Move it inside the useEffect callback.
>   Alternatively, wrap the 'pace' definition into its own useCallback()
>   Hook  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

I thought I was already calling inside the useEffect callback. Can someone explain? The documentation doesn't say much about useEffect and its callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables that are declared `const` are still variables. In this case you redefine `counting` each render cycle, but being const means the variable `counting` can't be reassigned a value *during* a render cycle. Because you redefine it each render cycle is the reason you see the second warning.

If nothing else calls `counting` then just move it inside the effect. This removes the need to include it in the dependency array, and only gets defined when the effect's callback triggers.

```
useEffect(() => {
  let interval = null;

  const counting = () => {
    setCurrentTimeMs(currentTimeMs => currentTimeMs + 1);
  };

  if (isOn) {
    interval = setInterval(counting, 1000);
  } else {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [isOn]);
```

***Note 1:*** I converted updating `setCurrentTimeMs` to use a functional state update since state depends on previous state.

***Note 2:*** I also removed `currentTimeMs` from the dependency array so you don't set more than one interval each time state updates when `isOn` is true. **[edit]** Actually, this is ok since the cleanup function handles clearing the interval set from previous cycle. Should still remove `currentTimeMs` though as it isn't necessary.

[image: Edit toggleable set interval effect]